# Blazor WASM unbound breakpoints .net 6 preview7 in vscode 1.60

Tags: visual-studio-code, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Debugging Blazor works fine in vs code 1.60 with .net 5.0. *, But after installing net 6.0.100-preview.7, in new apps ( dotnet new blazorwasm) breakpoints are not loaded, although if you run the application created with .net 5 sdk, everything continues to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the same thing with debugging in .net6 release

the BlazorWasmDebuggingExtension extension is only available in version 1.1.0, so I updated it for .net6 manually: in the folder ".vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.blazorwasm-companion-1.1.0" replaced the necessary version numbers in the config and libraries "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" on 6.0